# how to exclude certain files in folder when rendering from express using files.foreach

Tags: express, ejs

I have the code below in my index.js file for an express/node app

```
// BACKGROUNDS
fs.readdir('public/img/backgrounds/',function(err,files){
  if(err) throw err;
  files.forEach(function(file){
    myBGfiles.push(file);
  });
});
```

It pulls all the files in that folder, including the gitignore and ds_store.  Is there a way to ignore these files when doing this?

I attempted an if statement to exclude them but I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this, and also unsure of the syntax needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an if statement. 
The `array.forEach();` method cannot be stopped mid-iteration [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

So you either need to ignore the files you want to ignore by using an if statement or need to use another kind of loop, which you can `continue` by using an if statement as well. The difference will be pretty much this (note the difference of checking for `isBackgroundFile` and `isNonBackgroundFile`:

Note that I took the liberty to do some code formatting.

using `array.forEach();`:

```
fs.readdir('public/img/backgrounds/', function(err, files) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (isBackgroundFile(file)) {
            myBGfiles.push(file);   
        }
    });
});
```

or using ECMAscript 6 `for .. of ..`

```
fs.readdir('public/img/backgrounds/', function(err, files) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    for (let file of files) {
        if (isNonBackgroundFile(file))   {
            continue;
        }

        myBGfiles.push(file);
    }
});
```

And if your version of Node doesn't support ECMAscript 6 you can use the `for .. in ..`

```
fs.readdir('public/img/backgrounds/', function(err, files) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    for (var file in files) {
        if (files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
            if (isNonBackgroundFile(file))   {
                continue;
            }

            myBGfiles.push(file);
        }
    }
});
```

For the `isBackgroundFile` and isNonBackgroundFile` you could do something like this:

```
var path = require('path');

function isBackgroundFile(file) {
    // check file extension or something.
    if(path.extname(file) === ".png" || path.extname(file) === ".jpg") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isNonBackgroundFile(file) {
    return !isBackgroundFile(file);
}
```

If you're wondering whether it's possible to add options to `fs.readdir` to only return files with for example specific extensions, that's not possible.

There's a library which is able to do that, [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) but I'd say the if statement alternative perfectly fulfills your needs.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, if I could vote for it twice I would, worked perfectly.